# Hard drive failing only on Sunday morning

Tags: boot, hard-drive, home-directory, time

A couple of weeks ago I started to have a problem with my HDD in my system failing to mount during boot. My system is set up to boot the root partition, / , from an SSD them boot /home from an HDD. The problem comes with the system failing to mount /home and the drive being in an error state. It would eventually boot after a couple of tries.
It may sound like a hardware issue but I have S.M.A.R.T tested the drive 3 times with no problems returned, replaced the SATA and power cable to the drive. At first I thought it was due to cold weather, then I thought it was because the SSD might be booting faster than the HDD can spin up so I added a boot delay. I even updated the BIOS. I was having nothing more than the occasional issue with it but would eventually get it to boot.
Today I have realized, it only fails to boot on Sunday mornings. This has been persistent for the past 3 weeks. It is the most bizarre thing I have ever seen but I have no problems with it any other day. Once about noon hits on Sunday, it works no problem again.
What is the reason for this?
Thank you! Let me know if I can provide any additional information

Comment: That is odd, day or time should not make any difference.  The only thing I can think of, is if a file check or something has been scheduled for Sunday morning.  This should have to be done by someone, not something a computer would do on it's own(besides file checks at boot up)

Comment: How can I check this? Check if something is scheduled? Cron tabs?

Comment: Disabling cron using “systemctl disable cron” did not work

Comment: This could be environmental.  It is really hard to pinpoint something like this, but in the past I have helped customers when I worked for CompUSA having similar boot issues with their computer.  They brought in their computer to us and it booted every single time on our test bench without a problem.  They would take it home and it would not boot in their computer room.  They moved it to another room and it booted fine.  Even with an extension cord into the room that they had problems in it wouldn't boot.  They think it was caused by a power box outside the room causing interference.

Comment: Maybe look around if anything is happening until noon on Sundays around your area.  This does not sound like an OS issue.

Comment: Only thing can think of is to leave computer on Saturday night and turn off Sunday night and see if Monday morning is different.

Comment: Hmmm I’m pretty sure I have left it on Saturday night and booted it just fine again Monday morning but I will try that again.

Comment: I will also try moving the computer to a different spot in the house to see if that changes anything

Comment: At this point I have eliminated a hardware issue, and if it’s not OS related then the only other option is environmental

Comment: I have discovered it doesn't work Friday morning either. Seems to just sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. Could this still be an environmental issue or could it be something else? What can I do to fix it?